# How to make tun0 not be the default route

Tags: debian, routing, openvpn

I'd like to use openVPN client, but only have 1 application use the VPN, keeping the rest of the traffic going via eth0.

My client is debian.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

remove `redirect-gateway` option from configfile, and add `route <ip> 255.255.255.255 <gw>`

Comment: hmm, I don't have redirect-gateway in the config file?

Comment: then use `redirect-private`